# Configuring the PayPal Password Management Script

Tags: paypal

In the 'PayPal Password Management' Installation Guide, at the beginning of chapter 3 (Configuring the PayPal Password Management Script), are the following instructions:

> First, install the Perl script. This is a four-step process.
>
> 1. Download the package and copy it to a temporary directory on your web server.
> 2. Uncompress the file with the following command: gzip -dc filename.tar.gz | tar -x.
>      The temporary directory should now contain the following files: paypal.pl, README.

My question is with regards to step #1: "Download the package" from where???

Is there any place on the web where I can find this package, or even just the PERL script paypal.pl?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got it.

The PERL script can be downloaded from the same place as the Installation Guide:

First, obtain the PayPal Perl script from the PayPal web site:

```
Log into PayPal and click the Merchant Tools tab.

Click Subscriptions and Recurring Payments.
```

While you're here, make note of the Subscriptions Password Management checkbox.

To use Password Management for a subscription, you'll need to enable this feature.

Click the "IPN and server modifications" link.

Click the "Download Perl script" link and save the Manual and Script to your hard drive.

The credit goes to:

http://www.screw-paypal.com/resources/paypal_magic/6_managing_subscriptions.html.